# Parsing object in ng-options for angularjs select drop down using nested json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-options, angularjs-ng-model

I have the following json:

```
  [
{
    "normal" :{
        "font": "Burlington Script.ttf",
        "fontFamily": "sf_burlington_scriptregular",
        "fontName": "Burlington Script"
    },
    "bold" : {
        "font": "SF_Burlington_Script_Bold.ttf",
        "fontFamily": "sf_burlington_scriptbold",
        "fontName": "Burlington Script"
    },
    "italic" : {
        "font": "SF_Burlington_Script_Italic.ttf",
        "fontFamily": "sf_burlington_scriptitalic",
        "fontName": "Burlington Script"
    },
    "bold-italic": {
        "font": "SF_Burlington_Script_Bold_Italic.ttf",
        "fontFamily": "sf_burlington_scriptBdIt",
        "fontName": "Burlington Script"
    }

},

{
    "normal" :{
        "font": "Some_Script.ttf",
        "fontFamily": "Some_scriptregular",
        "fontName" : "Some Script"
    },
    "bold" : {
        "font": "Some_Script_Bold.ttf",
        "fontFamily": "Some_scriptbold",
        "fontName" : "Some Script"
    },
    "italic" : {
        "font": "Some_Script_Italic.ttf",
        "fontFamily": "Some_scriptitalic",
        "fontName" : "Some Script"
    },
    "bold-italic": {
        "font": "Some_Script_Bold_Italic.ttf",
        "fontFamily": "Some_scriptBdIt",
        "fontName" : "Some Script"
    }

}
]
```

what i want to do is display the fontName in the drop down under "normal" only and have the value be fontFamily.

I have tried

```
 <select                
      ng-model="selectedFont"
      ng-options="fonts as fonts.normal.fontName for fonts in designFonts" required>
 </select>
```

but no luck. i am setting $scope.designFonts in my controller to whatever the json is.

Comment: You mean ng-model needs to be font-family? http://plnkr.co/edit/AydiOR?p=preview

Comment: Use [this](http://jsfiddle.net/derkoe/KN9xx/presentation/) JSFiddle as a guidance.

Comment: No the option value i want it to be set to fontName so drop down should display Burlington Script and the option value should be sf_burlington_scriptregular instead of just 0 1 ...

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/2vj4PK?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize the `select as` part of the [ng-option expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#usage) to set what you need to set the value of the ng-model when an option is selected. So `fonts.normal.fontFamily as fonts.normal.fontName for fonts in designFonts` and use a track by to have the option value set with respective value (*track by is always applied to value*).

Try:-

```
  <select                
     ng-model="selectedFont"
     ng-options="font as font.normal.fontName for font 
                   in designFonts track by font.normal.fontFamily" 
  required></select>
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/AydiOR?p=preview)**

If you use `font.normal.fontFamily as font.normal.fontName` will set ng-model with the respective fontFamily if you need the entire object as ng-model then use the way you have now.

---

Well there is a possibly ng-select bug, you cannot use `select as` with `track by` together on the same field which causes issue in selection, though `ng-model` gets applied. So you could use:-

```
 ng-options="font as font.normal.fontName for font 
                   in designFonts track by font.normal.fontFamily"
```

But you can't

```
 ng-options="font.normal.fontFamily as font.normal.fontName for font 
                   in designFonts track by font.normal.fontFamily"
```

Comment: would you be able to tell me how i can set a default selected font. $scope.selectedFont returns the object of that font which is great but when i try to set $scope.selectedFont on the page load as one of the fontFamily values it doesnt seem to work